# why stompit.ConnectFailover would generate thousands of consumers

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic

I use the code shown below, to setup a connection for an active message queue via nodejs

```js
    var reconnectOptions = {
      'maxReconnects': 10,
      connect: {
        connectHeaders: {
          'heart-beat': '5000,5000'
        }
      }
    };
var servers = [mqConfig.connectOption];
var manager = new stompit.ConnectFailover(servers, reconnectOptions);

  manager.connect(function(error, client, reconnect){
  client.subscribe(mqConfig.receiveHeaders, function(error, message) {


    client.on('error', function(error) {
      reconnect();
    });

    message.readString('utf-8', function (error, body) {

      if (error) {
        console.log('read message error ' + error.message);
        return;
      }
    ....
```

It works to connect to activemq and send out messages, but it would generate thousands of consumers with session id equal to `-1`. Is there any reason for that to happen, any ideas?